# show/hide div section based on where the page is redirected from?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, redirect, toggle

I have two php files which redirect like this

```
`header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?div=subscription');`
`header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?div=stusearch');`
```

On the "usrsecuredpage.php" I have a few javascrip toggle links on page which show and hide div sections. this is the code:

```
<li><a href="javascript:toggle('subscription')"><b>Subscription Details</b></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:toggle('stusearch')"><b>Personal Information</b></a></li>
```

clicking the subscription toggle link shows subscription detail and hides personal information and vise versa..

I would like the headers being supplied by php pages to automatically show relevant div section. for example when header `header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?div=subscription');` is received from php page i would like subscription detail section to toggle and show up..

how can i do this?

Comment: I would solve this by adding a hash to the URL which specifies which DIV you want shown or hidden. Then write a JavaScript function which (after `window.load`) does the magic.

Comment: mblase75: can you please give me an example, im not good at javascripting.. thnx

Answer (score 3):

Add a query string parameter to your URL and have the page show or hide the div based on the query string parameter.

For example,

```
header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?ShowDiv=true');
```

Then, in the resulting page, you can check the value of that variable by using the global variable $_GET, like this:

```
$_GET['ShowDiv']
```

Using this variable, you can show or hide the div accordingly.  Let me know if I can provide any more detail...

Comment: ok let's say im passing this parameter  header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?id=showstuinfo');  on the usrsecuredpage.php how do i check if result received is showstuinfo and in that case how do i toggle 'stusearch' ??

Comment: I mean using this variable that i got from $_get how do i toggle a link??

Comment: Is usrsecuredpage.php generated via php?  If so, just wrap an IF block around the div that you want to show conditionally.

Comment: usrsecuredpage.php gets all data from php sql query.. what should be an if statement to toggle divs based on variables received via URL?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jquery for this if you can ...  Just include the jquery library and then use this code ...

```
$("#yourDiv").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *GET* parameters that you can pass through the URL.  For example, in your PHP file which redirects back to the original page, type the following for your redirection code:

```
header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?div=sub'); // div='sub' or div='stu'
```

Now, in the `usrsecuredpage.php` file, include the following code near the top to find out which div to have open at the start:

```
$openDiv = $_GET['div'];
```

At this point the `$openDiv` variable will contain either 'sub', 'stu', or will not be defined (if you didn't include the parameter in the URL).  You can use `isset($openDiv)` to find out whether it is defined or not.  If it is defined, then compare against the value of $openDiv to find out which div to have open at the start.  For example:

```
// initialize display of both divs to none
$subscriptionVisibility = "none";
$stusearchVisibility = "none";

// now, based on value of $openDiv, set above vars
if (isset($openDiv) && strcomp($openDiv,"sub") == 0)
   $subscriptionVisibility = "inline";
else if (isset($openDiv))
   $stusearchVisibility = "inline";

.
.
.

// now, whenever you create the divs, use their visibilities
echo "<div class='jotform-form' id='subscriptionDiv' style='display:$subscriptionVisibility;'></div>";
echo "<div class='jotform-form' id='stusearchDiv' style='display:$stusearchVisibility;'></div>";
```

In this example if your parameter was anything other than 'sub', the code assumes it was 'stu'.  So if your parameter was 'bla', it would still make the stusearch div visible.

This may not be the best code for this solution, however, it should be enough to push you in the right direction.  The overall approach is: pass the parameter in the URL string as a *GET* parameter (as I have shown), and then, in the `usrsecuredpage.php` file, use that parameter to determine which div should be open from the start.

Comment: that would be my choice of code, how ever im already using div style to toggle these links like this  <div class="jotform-form" id="scheduler" style="display: none;">

Comment: It's the same thing.  I updated my example to use `display:none` and `display:inline` instead.  Wherever you write your divs, start a PHP tag using `<?` and after you are done "echo'ing" your divs, end it using `?>`

Comment: can we do something like = if $openDiv == 'sub'
   subscriptionDiv = "show";
else if $openDiv == 'stu'
   stusearchDiv = "show";

Comment: @ABI, please provide the code for your `usrsecuredpage.php` and I'll implement it for you in the manner I have shown above. I am pretty much doing what you said if `($openDiv == 'sub')` is roughly equivalent to if `(strcomp($openDiv,"sub"))`. The only thing I'm adding is the HTML writing code. You need to write out the HTML code differently to start the div out as visible or hidden. Include your code here and I'll modify it for you if you are having trouble implementing this code.