# javascript toggle based on php header get value?

Tags: php, javascript, header, toggle

I have two links which show / hide div sections (inside each div section i am running sql queries)

```
<li><a href="javascript:toggle('subscription')"><b>Subscription Details</b></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:toggle('stusearch')"><b>Personal Information</b></a></li>
```

while getting query results back to original page, i would be passing parameters via url and would like to receive them on usrsecuredpage.php which contains the various javascript toggles which i would like to show/hide based on the header i get.

for example is i get

header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?id=personalinfo');

i would like to toggle "stusearch"

if the header is

header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php?id=subscriptioninfo');

then toggle "subscription"

Please help

Comment: I realize you only did so because you have not received an answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233674/show-hide-div-section-based-on-where-the-page-is-redirected-from but please avoid posting duplicates. If you first question did not result in an acceptable answer then using the *edit* button you can rephrase your question to be more accurate or more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that.  The PHP code runs on the server.  Javascript runs on the client.

If all you want to do is a simple redirect, do it with Javascript.

```
function toggle(name) {
  window.location = "usrsecuredpage.php?id=" + name;
}
```

Comment: na, im trying to show hide div tags linked to these toggles based on value i get from url from another php page.. hope that makes sense

Comment: So you want to make an Ajax-type call to an external PHP page and toggle DIV visibility based on the return value?  Have you looked into jQuery?

Comment: each hidden div has a form in it, which sends data to php, which returns data back to original page, however im trying to display the data within the div section itself, the data comes back fine except that i would like to get the div section to toggle and show up where the data is shown rather than the original page with all divs hidden

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
function get(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
```

then change the html to

```
<li><a href="toggle(get('id'))"><b>Subscription Details</b></a></li>
<li><a href="toggle(get('id'))"><b>Personal Information</b></a></li>
```

Comment: Basically the function I added will return the value of the url variable you want to _get()_ so you can run a check against that and hide the button / container accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In php header sends headers... If you are visiting usrsecuredpage.php and want to know what id is you need to use the $_GET superglobal.

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 'personalinfo') {
   echo '<div>...';
}
else if ($_GET['id'] == 'subscriptioninfo') {
   echo '<div>...';
}
```

Update:

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the divs on the page regardless and the appropriate div to show up based on the id passed to the php script.  If so, you could do this at the bottom of your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if ($_GET['id'] == 'personalinfo'): ?>
    toggle('stusearch');
<?php elseif ($_GET['id'] == 'subscriptioninfo'): ?>
    toggle('subscription');
<?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

It's kinda an ugly solution but it works.

Comment: This could work except that i have divs hidden by default and only show up when toggle link is clicked  href="javascript:toggle('subscription')"   so optimally i would like to get the javascript toggle to get on if statement rather than the div it self

Comment: Edited the answer above... If I'm understanding correctly it would be easiest to mix php and js.  If you go past 2 divs, there's a more elegant way to do it.  You could also parse the querystring strictly in Javascript if you want, but it's a little more involved.

Comment: actually on the same lines i found this solution : <?php 
    if ($_GET['div'] == 'success') {
       $showdiv = 'success';
    }
 elseif
 ($_GET['div'] == 'subscription') {
       $showdiv = 'subscription';
    }
 elseif
 ($_GET['div'] == 'failed') {
       $showdiv = 'failed';
    }
 elseif
 ($_GET['div'] == 'info') {
       $showdiv = 'stusearch';
    }
 elseif
 ($_GET['div'] == 'scheduler') {
       $showdiv = 'scheduler';
    }
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.getElementById('".$showdiv."').style.display = 'block';</script>";

?>